# How to list windows folders with rules

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an structure like this

```
folder1>subfolder1>sub-subfolder
      >subfolder2>sub-subfolder
      >subfolder3>sub-subfolder
      >subfolder4>sub-subfolder

folder2>subfolder1>sub-subfolder
      >subfolder2>sub-subfolder
      >subfolder3>sub-subfolder
      >subfolder4>sub-subfolder
```

I want to list this folders like this:

```
folder1>subfolder1
folder1>subfolder2
folder1>subfolder3
folder1>subfolder4

folder2>subfolder1
folder2>subfolder2
folder2>subfolder3
folder2>subfolder4
```

I want show only the first subfolders of the main folder in a txt archive.

I tryied with the command `dir /a:d /s /b | sort > lista.txt`, but this code show all folders.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `for /D %%a in (*) do (for /D %%b in ("%%a\*") do echo %%a^>%%~Nb) & echo/`

Comment: @double-beep yes, i want to show only the firsts subfolders of main folder.

Comment: @Aacini i tryied this but i can't put the locations in a txt archive.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `tree` like this:

```
> tree
├───folder1
│   ├───subfolder1
│   │   └───sub-subfolder
│   ├───subfolder2
│   │   └───sub-subfolder
│   ├───subfolder3
│   │   └───sub-subfolder
│   └───subfolder4
│       └───sub-subfolder
└───folder2
    ├───subfolder1
    │   └───sub-subfolder
    ├───subfolder2
    │   └───sub-subfolder
    ├───subfolder3
    │   └───sub-subfolder
    └───subfolder4
        └───sub-subfolder
```

[Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)s slightly changed command (parentheses,redirection) works perfect for me on cmdline

```
(@for /D %a in (*) do @for /D %b in ("%a\*") do @echo %a^>%~Nb)>Lista.txt
```

or in a batch-file

```
@Echo off
(for /D %%a in (*) do for /D %%b in ("%%a\*") do echo %%a^>%%~Nb)>Lista.txt
```

---

```
> type Lista.txt
folder1>subfolder1
folder1>subfolder2
folder1>subfolder3
folder1>subfolder4
folder2>subfolder1
folder2>subfolder2
folder2>subfolder3
folder2>subfolder4
```